# Trimming empty string or spaces in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

What happens when you try and trim an empty string or a bunch of spaces in SQL Server? Does it become `null` or `''`?

Comment: Have you tried it? You could answer this question for yourself with about 20 characters of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy way to test string manipulations, manually throw some strings together and find out:

```
;with cte as (SELECT '   0   ' AS col 
              UNION SELECT '      ' AS col 
              )
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(col)) as col
FROM cte
```

Which returns a zero and a blank string. To get a `NULL` you'd have to use `NULLIF()`

Answer (score 5):

trimming will only leave you with a blank space.

```
ltrim(rtrim(' '))
```

but

```
nullif(ltrim(rtrim(' ')),'')   will give you null
```

Answer (score -1):

I run this command while updating all row.
Revise your need.
For example:

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnName, CHAR(10), CHAR(32)), CHAR(13), CHAR(32)), CHAR(160), CHAR(32)),CHAR(9),CHAR(32))))
```